# Flutter: Where to locate auth file when connecting to google cloud api

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-oauth, google-vision

I am trying to use google vision API from a Flutter app. I am using the google_vision package: https://pub.dev/packages/google_vision.
From the example in this page: https://pub.dev/packages/google_vision/example I need to use an auth.json file in order to create the Google vision project. The question is where can I put the file so that the app can find it.

I tried to add to put the file in the asset folder and update the pubspec.yaml file. But I still get the error code:

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/auth/auth.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

The line of code that I use is:

```
final googleVision = await GoogleVision.withJwt('assets/auth/auth.json');
```

As an alternative if there is a way to use an API Key instead of json file it's also a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access asset files, because assets are bundled with the application and are not part of the device's file system. You should use the `rootBundle` from `package:flutter/services.dart` instead to read the asset data and then store it again in the device's file system like the example of the `google_vision` package on GitHub shows.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<String> getFileFromAsset(String assetFileName,
    {String? temporaryFileName}) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/auth/$assetFileName');
  final buffer = byteData.buffer;

  final fileName = temporaryFileName ?? assetFileName;
  final filePath = await getTempFile(fileName);

  await File(filePath).delete();
  await File(filePath).writeAsBytes(
      buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

  return filePath;
}

Future<String> getTempFile([String? fileName]) async {
  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  return '${tempDir.path}${Platform.pathSeparator}${fileName ?? UniqueKey().toString()}';
}
```

You can then create your `GoogleVision`-Instance like this:

```dart
final jwtFromAsset = await getFileFromAsset('auth.json');
final googleVision = await GoogleVision.withJwt(jwtFromAsset);
```

Comment: Thanks nibbo for the detailed response. I copied the code as is and it works fine !